# how to call iconv which is not found in ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15 in FPDF

Tags: fpdf, iconv

recently I was studying fpdf ,, and finally got hindered by displaying symbols. I've tried searching for references on google but it doesn't really help .., that's why I'm trying to ask here, (sorry if this is just a trivial question)

```
$this->SetX(10);
$this->Cell(15,10,iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8", "∑"),1,0,'C',1);
$this->SetX(15);
$this->Cell(15,10,iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", "∑"),1,0,'C',1);
$this->SetX(20);
$this->Cell(15,10,iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-15", "∑"),1,0,'C',1);
```

from the script above, I get the result "â‘‘ "or blank without a result,,,, how to display ∑ ?

Comment: `chr(83)` from the Symbol font is a ∑, as you can see [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/fontdump.pdf).

Comment: @Olivier how to use it in fpdf iconv??

Comment: Don't use iconv(). The Symbol font doesn't use a standard encoding.

Comment: @Olivier thank full,,,,